# Convert array to string with quotes

Tags: ruby

How do I convert an array like:

```
[["hello"], ["world"]]
```

To:

```
"hello", "world"
```

I tried `array.join(',')`

But this would return:

```
"hello world"
```

What I want is a string with qoutes: `""hello", "world""`.

---

**For completeness:**

I am trying to build this query from the array.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column IN ("hello", "world");
```

Comment: I am trying to add this into a query.

Comment: Is it for active record models?

Comment: I am not using rails, just pure ruby with Mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
array.map{|s| "\"#{s}\""}.join(', ')
```

Update:

With structure `[['a'],['b']` do:

```
array.map{|s| "\"#{s.first}\""}.join(', ')
```

Comment: updated my question. I'm getting another error with this though. I'll try to double check.

Comment: Aaah, I had a mistake, the array actually looked like `[["a"],["b"]]`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do like this:

```
array.map { |a| a.first.inspect }.join(', ')
# => "\"hello\", \"world\""
```

**Update**: a couple of alternative solutions:

```
array.flatten.map(&:inspect).join(', ')
# => "\"hello\", \"world\""
```

Using the `String#quote` method from [Ruby Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets):

```
require 'facets/string/quote'
array.flatten.map(&:quote).join(', ')
# => "\"hello\", \"world\""
```

Comment: Care to explain why the inspect?

Comment: Why not? In this case it produces exactly the requested output and, IMO, is clearer than an interpolation.

Comment: I agree, seems cleaner too.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to use the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection#quote` method. This will not only handle the case of escaping the outer quotes but also any lingering inner quotes in a long VARCHAR or TEXT field.